# How to set up PhpStorm correctly? Сan't run PHPUnit on Laravel 8 on Windows 10. Call to undefined function Tests\Unit\is_id_term()

Tags: laravel, windows, phpunit, phpstorm

I have installed PHPUnit globally and set up an environment variable "path" by, so it runs by command `phpunit.phar`

I created a file with a custom function in the "app" folder:

```
function is_id_term(string $q, &$id = null, string $name = 'id'): bool {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

After that I added at the autoload section in the composer.json file in the following line:

```
"files": [
    "./app/functions.php"
]
```

Then I ran the command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Then created unit test in a `tests/unit/` folder:

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class IsIdTermTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testOne()
    {
        $res = is_id_term('id: 1');
        $this->assertTrue($res);
    }

    public function testString()
    {
        $res = is_id_term('id:lucas');
        $this->assertFalse($res);
    }
}
```

If I run these tests using the green button in the upper right corner of PhpStorm, I get the following error:

```
C:\localserver\php8.0.2\php.exe C:\Users\webgr\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\laravel\installer\bin\phpunit.phar --no-configuration C:\Users\webgr\projects\my-blog\tests --teamcity --cache-result-file=C:\Users\webgr\projects\my-blog\.phpunit.result.cache
Testing started at 19:00 ...
PHPUnit 9.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Error : Call to undefined function Tests\Unit\is_id_term()
 C:\Users\webgr\projects\my-blog\tests\Unit\IsIdTermTest.php:11
```

After starting the test using the green button, file appears in the root folder of the project .phpunit.result.cache with this content

```
C:37:"PHPUnit\Runner\DefaultTestResultCache":230:{a:2:{s:7:"defects";a:2:{s:32:"Tests\Unit\IsIdTermTest::testOne";i:4;s:35:"Tests\Unit\IsIdTermTest::testString";i:4;}s:5:"times";a:2:{s:32:"Tests\Unit\IsIdTermTest::testOne";d:0.004;s:35:"Tests\Unit\IsIdTermTest::testString";d:0;}}}
```

But, if I execute the command in terminal:

```
phpunit.phar
```

then all tests pass without errors.

In the same way, PhpStorm finds this function without problems if I click on its name while in some other file.

Can you please tell me how to set up PhpStorm? And what is my mistake?

Comment: Seems like your autoload does not apply though. Have you configured it in PhpStorm? Please have a look into Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Test Frameworks. Set your configuration (phpunit.xml) and try again.

Comment: After starting the test using the green button, file appears in the root folder of the project .phpunit.result.cache with this content C:37:"PHPUnit\Runner\DefaultTestResultCache":230:{a:2:{s:7:"defects";a:2:{s:32:"Tests\Unit\IsIdTermTest::testOne";i:4;s:35:"Tests\Unit\IsIdTermTest::testString";i:4;}s:5:"times";a:2:{s:32:"Tests\Unit\IsIdTermTest::testOne";d:0.004;s:35:"Tests\Unit\IsIdTermTest::testString";d:0;}}}

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

with

```
use Tests\TestCase;
```

The `artisan make:test {name} --unit` command seems to always generate the template with the TestCase referenced as `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`

Comment: In such a case, I get the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PHPUnit\TestCase" not found

Comment: Using ```use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;``` throws an error.

Did you try ```use Tests\TestCase;``` ?

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling the project, everything worked by itself, but I still don't know what was the cause of the error. I believe that the reason was that I created the project before I installed PHPUnit globally and configured XDebug. Although of course I could be wrong.

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is related to Composer, it did not update the new file.